# Is it ok to use pneumatic tools underwater

Tags: tools, water, concrete

I have a concrete that is stuck underwater. The concrete piece is too heavy. I think that I could break it into small pieces with my pneumatic impact drill.

Comment: How deep is the water? Would the whole tool be submerged, or just the chisel?

Comment: Check these out [Hydraulic Tools](http://www.underwatertools.net/SHT-page.htm).

Comment: It' 8 feed underwater. It's close to my dock. I can try to use a giraffe jack, one of 2"x6x8' with 2 chains. I will jack the piece with the jack and a chain than tight the second chain with the 2"x6". I lower the jack and retight the first chain. Repeat until the piece of concrete go out of the water. I will try to move or break it outside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do light underwater work as a part of my job. One thing I do is drill in rock underwater with a CP9 rock drill. This is a pneumatic tool but is designed to work both above and under water. It works great as long as it is properly lubed before and disassembled and lubed as soon as possible after the job is done.

I have no first hand experience of other tools, but according to a colleague it is perfectly fine to use more or less any pneumatic tools underwater, he often uses cheap ones and says that they do get the job done.

Edit: I have since I posted this answer used multiple cheap pneumatic tools underwater. I can report that I have had no problems at all in doing so, as long as the tool is disassembled within a day (preferrably ASAP) after being used and lubricated throughout.

Answer (score 5):

As a salvage diver, I know that a pneumatic tool will work in the water.

The only difference between a $2,000 impact driver used at Haliburton and a $20 Harbor Freight 'wonder tool' is all that high precision stainless steel internal components (brass, bronze, stainless, etc.). With your $20 HF wonder tool, just make sure to soak it in MINERAL OIL after use (tap the air SLIGHTLY to fully lubricate everything)...and drain it well, with another 'tap' to clear it before re-entering the water...oh, and SALT WATER is HELL on pneumatics not specifically made for them.

ALL THAT SAID...be aware, HIGH AIR RATE pneumatics produce COPIOUS AMOUNTS of air bubbles!!! In doing so, you MIGHT not be able to see, during your process...this of course, is MOST PREVALENT on the most-dangerous tools, like die grinders, p-grinders, etc...and lowest on things like impact drills, wrenches or 'jaw cutters'.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement. Your answer is probably technically correct, but consider toning down the sarcasm and snide references to other users. The Stack Exchange network has a "be nice" policy so that all users feel welcome, even if they're wrong. With a little more rep, you can vote and comment on other posts to express disagreement. You can also post the correct information in your own answers, which will rise to the top via other people's voting when they see the brilliance in your post. Your answers will get a much better reception if you just stick to the technical information.  :-)

Comment: One thing that hasn't been addressed is the vibration dampening effect of the water, so that the effect of impact tools is different underwater than it is on land.  If you could add a few sentences about that, it would add value that's missing from the thread.

Comment: I'd rather have a 'smart aleck' response that is technically correct, than to be 'better-than-thou' like MOST of the responders to this question, AND BE AS WRONG AS THEY ARE! Between rednecks that have no clue what they are saying (other than they tried it and didn't kill themselves), and others that have no clue they are wrong....you dare address me and ask me to 'tone it down'? I've dove under water for 20-years, and KNOW what the tools do...ask yourself, if you wouldn't preach to a sarcastic Neal deGrasse Tyson for astrophysics snydeness, why would you address me, your only EXPERT here?!

Comment: Tell you what...keep your 'Stack Exchange Network', delete my response, and let the idiots, trolls and children teach each other falsehoods for the sake of 'niceness'. After all, this is 'Home Improvement Niceness', not 'Home Improvement Expertise'...you teach them, after all, you correct me and I'm the one with 8,000 dive hours and experience on Nitrox dives working oil platforms at 140-feet depth...you keep convincing yourself you're a referee...DELETE MY CONTRIBUTION...I WON'T BE BACK!!!

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer:  NO!  Any stoppage of outgoing air will suck water into the exhaust , cause hydolock, probably seize up and ruin your tool. Can you get bit extensions so the tool body is not underwater?  That would work.

Comment: Seems that everybody says NO, but scuba divers seem to say they've done it check [this](http://www.scubaboard.com/forums/technical-diving-specialties/155806-air-tools-underwater.html) out (might be a load of crap, but I found more than a few folks who say they've done it). I wouldn't try it, but I thought it was interesting that some people have. **Please don't try this at home** (I just found it amusing that folks even thought to try this).

Comment: Replying to shirlock homes - This is not a combustion engine. Since there is no exhaust valve, and this is also not a piston tool, water intrusion via the exhaust port would just be pushed out without harming anything.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have used harbor freight standard air drill underwater (fresh) and it worked fine.  Lots of bubbles though.  Be sure to use WD and dry it out after use.